# Porting openVPN config to Alpine Linux

Tags: openvpn, alpine-linux

I got an openVPN config file from my vpn provider. It worked great on Ubuntu, but on alpine, I got an error.

The following lines fail:

```
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

`/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` does not exists on alpine Linux but `/etc/openvpn/up.sh` and `/etc/openvpn/down.sh` do.

the log contains the following output:

```
Options error: --up script fails with '/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Options error: Please correct this error.
Use --help for more information.
```

Comment: Hi @Peter. Would you please add the error messages that you got! what do you mean by `The following lines fail:`? Failed where? and how you identified that these lines had failed? More clarifications will help us understand your problem much better, as a result give you an accurate answer ;-)

Comment: @Goro i added the logfile content.

Comment: @Goro the command returns `grep: /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/*: No such file or directory` but i do have `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Would you please `cd /etc/resolvconf/` then list the files i.e. `run ls` are there files in that path?

Comment: That directory does not exist.

Comment: You need to set up openvpn on alpine. See this link and let me know. https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_OpenVPN_server

Comment: @Goro that is for a server not a client.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the OpenVPN for Alpine Linux package does not include all the necessary scripts. If you know the address of the DNS servers your VPN provider uses, then you can use this simple workaround. You can also use a public DNS server such as Cloudflare DNS (1.1.1.1):

1. Enter the command: `sudo nano /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf`. The Nano text editor should open.
2. The file should be empty. Paste the following into the file:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   if [ -e /etc/resolv.conf.old ]; then
       mv /etc/resolv.conf.old /etc/resolv.conf
       chmod 777 /etc/resolv.conf
       exit
   fi
   mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.old
   cp /etc/resolv.conf.new /etc/resolv.conf
   chmod 777 /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file.
4. Enter the command: `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf.new`, then type `nameserver [address of VPN's DNS server]`.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file.

That should make a new copy of `resolv.conf` (`resolv.conf.new`),
and copy it to `resolv.conf` when the VPN activates, then copy back the old `resolv.conf` when the VPN ends.

Comment: (1) When does your ``/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf`` script run?  What runs it?  (2) Do you really believe that it’s a good idea to leave the `/etc/resolv.conf` file world-writable?  (3) When you say “type `nameserver` …”, do you mean type `n` `a` `m` `e` `s` `e` `r` `v` `e` `r`, or do you mean type the IP address of your name server? (You should use code formatting only for literal text, and not descriptions or placeholders.)

Comment: I'll just say, this similar to what I use on my setup so it may not be exactly what you want. The update-resolv-conf script runs whenever the .ovpn config file calls it (the lines 'up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf' and 'down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf'). In this case, it runs when the tunnel is established and terminated. I have changed my answer to make resolv.conf 755. When I say "type 'nameserver'", I mean type the word 'nameserver' and then '[SPACE]' and then type the DNS server's address.